# I hava json for filter. how can I traverse and generate json from It?

Tags: json, traversal

I have a json for filter .

```
"filter": {
        "logic": "or",
        "filters": [
            {
                "field": "substanceName",
                "operator": "contains",
                "value": "ou"
            },
            {
                "logic": "and",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "authorId",
                        "operator": "contains",
                        "value": "GD"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "substanceId",
                        "operator": "is",
                        "value": "RT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "logic": "or",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "firstName",
                        "operator": "contains",
                        "value": "ol"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "lastName",
                        "operator": "is",
                        "value": "Blood"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "field": "updatedBy",
                "operator": "contains",
                "value": "ou"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to transform this to like

```
OR:{
substance , AND:{authorId,substanceId}, OR:{firstName,lastName},updatedBy
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which programming language do you want to use?